# Does the first line of interaction output from lmer contain all levels of variables?

Tags: interpretation, lme4-nlme

I am using LMM from lmer to interpret my data. As the system of its output is dummy, so it should mean that the number of levels is always the same in every line of output.

For example, if I have three variables: color (red and white), sex (male or female), height (tall, low). The base line is always the second one in each variable.

The output is like this:

```
Red
Male
Tall
Red:Male
Red:male:tall
```

Then does it mean that on the first line, the DV of red and female and low is higher than white and female and low. Or it simply means that DV of red is higher than white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then does it mean that on the first line, the DV of red and female and
>   low is higher than white and female and low. Or it simply means that
>   DV of red is higher than white?

It means neither. For this info you'd have to look at the coefficients. This is just how R automatically dummy-coded your variables. `Red` means red is coded 1, white is coded 0; `Male` means male is coded 1, female is coded 0; etc.

Comment: Yeah supposed that the coeffecient is 2.00 so the first line will mean DV is higher in Red when white equals to zero, right?

Comment: Yes that's it. And conversely, if the coefficient is < 0 (e.g. -2.00), then the first line means the DV is lower for Red than for White.

Comment: So that means that the effects of sex and height are not considered at this line?

Comment: That's right. The effects of sex and height are considered at their respective lines ("Male" and "Tall", respectively). However, because they are involved in interactions, they are not interpreted as main effects. You should read up on interpreting regression coefficients with interactions before going any further.

Comment: Okay I will start from that. Thank you very much Patrick Coulombe.